# sed: Why does a file being edited in-place have modified lines doubled?

Tags: sed

The perils of working tired:

```
sed -i 's/foo/barbazqux/p' example.txt
```

This made the output file have two copies of any modified line.

Comment: See [section 5 of the sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq5.html).

Comment: Well that's not something new. If you read the documentation of the `p` command that's obvious. What's the question here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I hadn't removed the `p` flag from the end of the command.  I'd been doing this when testing it on the command line.

Correct command:

```
sed -i 's/foo/barbazqux/' example.txt
```